# How to perform a hitTest on an entity

Tags: playn

When user clicks on a moving or static object, ie an entity, how to listen to a mouse click event and perform a hitTest to see if the mouse was clicked on the target?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a listener to the pointer events. Below is a simple way to achieve that:

```
...
import playn.core.Pointer;

public class HitTestGame implements Game
{

    @Override
    public void init()
    {

        ...

        final HitTestGame self = this;

        // pointer
        pointer().setListener(new Pointer.Adapter() {

            @Override
            public void onPointerEnd(Pointer.Event event)
            {
                self.onPointerUp((int)event.x(), (int)event.y());
            }

            //public void onPointerStart(Pointer.Event event)
            //public void onPointerDrag(Pointer.Event event)

        });

        ...

    }

    public void onPointerUp(int x, int y)
    {

        // Do region checks here
        if ( (x >= entity.left() && x <= entity.right())
                && (y >= entity.top() && y <= entity.bottom()) )
        {
            System.out.println("Entity has been clicked!");
        }

    }

    ...

}
```